# Compile Error: Invalid type: Acccount at line 5 column 17, Please let me know what went wrong

Tags: apex

I tried to build basic apex class with List but compilation failed,

```
public class c1 {
    List<Account>acts= [select Name, Type, Industry, Phone, Fax 
                          from Account where Industry='Energy'];
    public List<Acccount> getacts(){
        return acts;  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just as the error suggests, there is no object type of 'Acccount'.  You have a typo.  You have Account spelled with 3 c's.

Change this

```
public List<Acccount> getacts(){
```

to this

```
public List<Account> getacts(){
```

Comment: easiest 40 rep pts ever earned :-)